# React Router V6 - Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have installed `react-router-dom`V6-beta. By following the example from a website I am able to use the new option `useRoutes` I have setup page routes and returning them in the `App.js` file.

After saving I am getting the following error:

***Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a  component.***

I am wondering If I am missing something here? I have created the pages inside the `src/pages` folder.

My code:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Outlet, useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';

// Pages
import Home from './pages/Home';
import About from './pages/About';
import Services from './pages/Services';
import Gallery from './pages/Gallery';
import Prices from './pages/Prices';
import Contact from './pages/Contact';

const App = () => {
    const routes = useRoutes([
        { path: '/', element: <Home /> },
        { path: 'o-nama', element: <About /> },
        { path: 'usluge', element: <Services /> },
        { path: 'galerija', element: <Gallery /> },
        { path: 'cjenovnik', element: <Prices /> },
        { path: 'kontakt', element: <Contact /> }
    ]);

    return routes;
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You should have a `<BrowserRouter>` (or any of [the provided routers](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/api.md)) higher up in the tree. The reason for this is that the `<BrowserRouter>` provides a history context which is needed at the time the routes are created using `useRoutes()`. Note that higher up means that it can't be in the `<App>` itself, but at least in the component that renders it.

Here's what your entry point could look like:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Comment: This appears to be untrue. https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dev/examples/basic/src/App.tsx

Comment: Look at main file https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dev/examples/basic/src/main.tsx

Answer (score 100):

I think the problem is that you still need to wrap `routes` (`Routes` / `useRoutes`) inside a `Router` element.

So an example would look something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useRoutes,
} from "react-router-dom";

const Component1 = () => {
  return <h1>Component 1</h1>;
};

const Component2 = () => {
  return <h1>Component 2</h1>;
};

const App = () => {
  let routes = useRoutes([
    { path: "/", element: <Component1 /> },
    { path: "component2", element: <Component2 /> },
    // ...
  ]);
  return routes;
};

const AppWrapper = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default AppWrapper;
```

Refactor according to your needs.

Comment: The `BrowserRouter as Router,`  was missing on my side.

Answer (score 16):

its means  in Your index js Or App JS wrap with BrowserRouter like this

```js
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>  // Like This here I am using
                <App />
           </BrowserRouter>
       </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root"),
);
```

Answer (score 12):

Mention below code in index.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
```

Answer (score 8):

Code: index.js

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router}  from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <Router>
    <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

app.js

```
function App() {
  return (
  <>
    <Routes>
    <Route path ="/" element={<Main />} />
    <Route path ="gigs" element={<Gigs />} />
    </Routes>
</>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to add your routes in index.js not in App.js. Your App.js is called from index.js. In the index.js your external page is called like this

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navbar />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just want to report on a similar issue -- as of writing (v6.2.1), it seems you actually encounter this error as well if you are importing from `react-router` instead of `react-router-dom`. A costly typo on my part.

I.e., make sure you are importing `Routes` and `Route` from `react-router-dom` and NOT `react-router`

```
// This is deceptively valid as the components exist, but is not the intended usage
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router';

// This works and is the intended usage
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Comment: As funny as it seems this is actually a valid solution, my app crashes because of this simple mistake. Thanks

Comment: This. My project worked fine through v6.3.0 of React Router, but as soon as I upgraded to 6.4.x, kaboom. Thanks for the fix on a very sticky problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
> Following codes works since react-router-dom syntax changed because of React 18.

  import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    import Header from './components/Header';
    import Login from './components/Login';
    import {
      BrowserRouter as Router,
      Routes,
      Route,
      useRoutes,
    } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Signup from './components/Signup';
    
    function AppRoutes() {
      const routes = useRoutes(
        [
          {path:'/',element:<Login/>},
          {path:'/signup',element:<Signup/>}
        ]
      )
      return routes;
    }
    function App(){
      return (
        <Router>
          <Header/>
          <AppRoutes />
        </Router>
      )
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const Routes = () => useRoutes([])
```

and then wrap it like this in App.js

```
<BrowserRouter> 
    <Routes />
</BrowserRouter>
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I had two different versions of react-router-dom being bundled.

If you're using npm/yarn workspaces, check that there is only one installed version of `react-router-dom` in the top-level node_modules folder

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error, then you forgot to wrap your `<Route>` tags with a `<BrowserRouter>` tag in App.js. By the way you can also wrap  around your entire App Component in index.js instead of wrapping it around your  Tags in App.js.