# Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**When i Write my  My Nav Bar Component Content Directly in My Router Component. It works Fine But When I write that content in a NavBar Component it Generates the following error

*Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a  component.*
.**

Im Using
   `"react-dom": "^17.0.2", "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.6",`

Following are my Components..

My NavBar Component:-

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
// import styles from './NavBar.module.css';
export const NavBar = () => {
  return (
      <nav>
        <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
        <Link to="/about"> About </Link>
        <Link to="/product"> Product </Link>
      </nav>
  );
}
```

My Route Component:-

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";

// importing Component's
import { Home } from "./Components/Home/Home";
import { About } from "./Components/About/About";
import { Products } from "./Components/Products/Products";
import { ProductItems } from "./Components/ProductItems/ProductItems";
import  {NavBar}  from "./Components/NavBar/NavBar";
import { Fotter } from "./Components/Fotter/Fotter";

export const RouterConfig = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route exact path="/product" component={Products} />
        <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductItems} />
        <Route path="*" component={() => <h2>404 Not Found </h2>} />
      </Switch>
      {/* <Fotter />' */}
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: For future reference, I believe the problem is you're using <Switch> tags, while in react-router 6, you should use <Routes> instead.

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Comment: I was using BrowserRouter as the direct parent of Routes, I see that instead that BrowserRouter or HashRouter or whatever you're using should go in the index file-

Answer (score 7):

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
```

Use in components App.js or above in index.js and wrap your component in Router.
Then the problem will disappear ;-)
In Your case I see two option:

1. **index.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**OR** use **App** Component instead of **RouterConfig** Component.

2. **App.js**

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";

// importing Component's
import { Home } from "./Components/Home/Home";
import { About } from "./Components/About/About";
import { Products } from "./Components/Products/Products";
import { ProductItems } from "./Components/ProductItems/ProductItems";
import  {NavBar}  from "./Components/NavBar/NavBar";
import { Fotter } from "./Components/Fotter/Fotter";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route exact path="/product" component={Products} />
        <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductItems} />
        <Route path="*" component={() => <h2>404 Not Found </h2>} />
      </Switch>
      {/* <Fotter />' */}
    </Router>
  );
};
```

I tried to explain it as best I could. Hope this helps you ;-) Best Greetings and Good Luck!
If you're still confused, check out here =>
[React Router V6 - Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425884/react-router-v6-error-useroutes-may-be-used-only-in-the-context-of-a-route)

Answer (score 0):

export is not running properly and causing an error. Can you retype it like below and try?:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
      <div>
        <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
        <Link to="/about"> About </Link>
        <Link to="/product"> Product </Link>
      </div>
  );
}
export default Navbar;
```

Also, you don't need curly brace for import statement.
`import NavBar from "./Components/NavBar/NavBar";`

If problem still persists, you can check your file paths because you are repeating folder names twice, it looks suspicious to me. Maybe you mean this:
`import NavBar from "./Components/NavBar";`

Comment: Abdulhakim ! 
I had Tried all of Your suggestion not worked... same  error again,,
(The Importing section in which u say im repeating is fine , no problem with it b/c  in NavBar folder im having NavBar.js ..That's why im writing it)

Comment: Then I guess problem lies with your custom hook useHref. You may find this question useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028117/react-hooks-error-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-the-body-of-a-function-compon