# Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component. It works when I directly put the url as localhost:3000/experiences

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a navbar that is rendered in every route while the route changes on click.

./components/navbar.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';



class Navbar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div id = 'navbar'>

                <div className='name-head'>
                    My Name
                </div>
            
            
                <div id = 'nav-links-container'>
                    
                    <Link to='/experiences'>
                        <div className = 'nav-links'>
                            Experiences
                        </div>
                    </Link>

                    <div className = 'nav-links'>
                        Projects
                    </div>

                    <div className = 'nav-links'>
                        Skills
                    </div>

                    <div className = 'nav-links'>
                        Resume
                    </div>

                </div>
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

./components/experiences.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Experiences extends Component {
    
    render() { 
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>hi</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
 
export default Experiences;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Experiences from './components/experience';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router, 
  Routes, 
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';



ReactDOM.render(

  <React.StrictMode>

    <Navbar />

    <Router>

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/experiences" element={<Experiences />} />
      </Routes>

    </Router>

  </React.StrictMode>,

  document.getElementById('root')
);


reportWebVitals();
```

The error doesn't come when I remove the `<Link>` from the experiences tag in navbar.
There is a similar question posted here: [Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69508954/error-usehref-may-be-used-only-in-the-context-of-a-router-component)
but doesn't help.

I'm using react router v6

Comment: On the components that you are building the routes, just put everything inside <Router></Router> tags. Not just the routes, but everything.

Comment: wow, class-based components, there is something I have not seen in some years.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

## Issue

You are rendering the navbar ***outside*** the routing context. The `Router` isn't aware of what routes the links are attempting to link to that it is managing. The reason routing works when directly navigating to `"/experiences"` is because the `Router` is aware of the URL when the app mounts.

```
<Navbar /> // <-- outside router!!

<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/experiences" element={<Experiences />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

## Solution

Move it ***inside*** the routing context so the `Router` is aware and can manage routing correctly.

```
<Router>
  <Navbar />
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/experiences" element={<Experiences />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

### `react-router-dom@6.4` Data APIs

If you are using the new Data routers you can hit this issue if you attempt to render a header/navbar *outside* the `RouterProvider` component. For this you can create a layout route that is part of the routing configuration passed to `createBrowserRouter` (*and other variants*).

Example:

```
const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/experiences" element={<Experiences />} />
    </Route>
  )
);
```

...

```
<RouterProvider router={router} />
```

Answer (score 34):

in React Route v6 you can solve this giving the route context to your entire App with  <**BrowserRouter**>

This is an complete example of index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { App }  from './components/App/App.jsx';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>  //that is the key
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Why is it specific only for React Router v6 ?

Comment: @Cat-Lord it is specific to version 6 because previous versions like 5 did not have this feature.

Comment: @Cat-Lord and Ale, it's not specific to v6, there's always been the issue of rendering links and routes outside of any routing context. It's just that v6 is the first major version to use a failing invariant check to throw an error. Previously there'd be no errors and you'd be stuck there wondering why nothing is working. As you can see, even with the error some still don't know what to do.

Answer (score 17):

If you are still having problem with this one, it is because `react-router-dom` relies on React context to work when you try to unit-test it. This makes `<Link />` or `<Route />` obsolete.
Try reading the [`react-router-dom` documentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing).

Instead of using

```js
render(<Example />)
```

that have either  or  inside it, you can try

```js
render(<MemoryRouter>
    <Example />
</MemoryRouter>)
```

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 9):

In **react-router-dom:6.x** and **react:18.x**, we should use the Router in the following way to resolve the issue:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { App }  from './App.js';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>  // Router
      <App /> // Application
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Yep, this works with Mantine UI demo as expected.

Answer (score 7):

Links are **inside** Navbar &
Navbar is **outside** of Router
=> links are **outside** of Router => Router will not manage Links

**Solution**

Move the Navbar into Router section. Example:

```
<Router>
  <Navbar /> // <===========
  <Routes>
    <Route />
    <Route />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Wrap navbar with BrowserRouter

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
<BrowserRouter>
    <AppNavBar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/wall" element={<WallPost />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 4):

Install in your project `React Router v6.`

```
npm install react-router-dom@6
```

Then use `BrowserRouter` in your `index.js` file, below like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
<React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

**React Router v6** this problem common one, you can simply replace *"**index.js**"* code. you will got solution-

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This error happens because `Link` component needs to reach out to `react-router` context object. Your Navbar component is using `Link` component but `Navbar` is not wrapped by router context.

A similar error happens in a testing environment. If you have a component that uses `Link` component and if you render this component in a testing environment, you will get the same error because `Link` component needs to access a router context. In the case of test environment:

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

// this will throw same error
test("testing", () => {
  render(<ComponentRendersLink/>); 
});
```

Solution in this case to wrap it with a router

```
// there are more router options
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";

render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <ComponentRendersLink />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your links just needs to be within a BrowserRouter component since you use v6
After  importing

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Link to='page'>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very much an edge case, but in my case it turned out a lib I develop had `react-router-dom: 6.0.2` installed and project that uses it `v6.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

@Yilmaz gives an excellent answer about this also occurring in a testing environment and I can confirm that is the case having experienced before and would like to offer a condensed answer of all the good ones given here.

Yes `Link` component will try to reach up and find the context object at the top of the component hierarchy and yes indeed this occurs in a testing environment as well.

Whenever we render one of these different react router component so something like `Link` or some other, even though we are in a test environment and we don’t really care about navigation at all, we still have to provide one of these three options available to us, we can try to wrap our component that we are trying to test in a:

1. BrowserRouter
2. HashRouter
3. MemoryRouter

How do you know which one to use? What is the difference?

Well, a `BrowserRouter` stores current URL in the address bar, a `HashRouter` stores current URL in the # part of the address bar and a `MemoryRouter` stores current URL in memory.

Like @Yilmaz I would also recommend going with a `MemoryRouter` in a testing environment, although there are some tests where `BrowserRouter` might be best to use long term.