# Browser rendering an empty Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to help me create a login form. but when rendering this sign-in component I get an empty browser but when I render other components without the Form groups and Form Control I get the contents in the browser.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import GoogleButton from 'react-google-button';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const SignIn = () => {

    return (
        <>
      
            <div className="p-4 box">
                <h2 className="mb-3">Bonnie Electronics</h2>
                <Form>

                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                        <Form.Control type='email' placeholder="email address" />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
                        <Form.Control type='password' placeholder="password" />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <div className="d-grid gap-2">
                         <Button type="submit" variant="primary">Login</Button>
                    </div>

                </Form>

                <hr />

                 <div>
                     <GoogleButton type="dark" className="g-button" />
                 </div>
                
            </div>
            <div className="p-4 box mt-3 text-center">
                Don't Have an Account? <Link to='/signup'>SignUp</Link>`enter code here`
            </div>

       </>
       
    )   
}

export default SignIn;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render this component SignIn **inside** the routing context because you are using **Link** from react **react-router-dom**

You are doing something like:

```
<SignIn /> // <-- This can't be outside router!

<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/whatever" element={<YourComp/>} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

You should move it inside the routing context so the Router is aware and can manage routing correctly.

```
<Router>
  <SignIn/>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/whatever" element={<YourComp/>} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

I have created ***Demo***:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-morning-0pt00?file=/src/SignIn.js

Also you can read more references **here**:

> [Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component. It works when I directly put the url as localhost:3000/experiences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70220413/error-usehref-may-be-used-only-in-the-context-of-a-router-component-it-wor)

Comment: Worked as fine as you suggested. Thanks a lot I have been starting projects. thinking that I made mistakes all along I have been working with Link and not knowing the components should be wrapped inside routs and Routers. Stack overflow is home

Comment: No problem mate :) everyday we learn new things and the best is to realize the things we have been doing bad fix it for future uses