# Deprecation notice: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this error every time I create a new React app:

> Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more: https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot

How can I fix it?

I created my React app using:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: See [Batching in React](https://www.shivamjha.io/blog/batching-in-react)

Answer (score 407, accepted):

In your file *index.js*, change to:

```javascript
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

#### For TypeScript

**Credit from comment section below answer**: [Kibonge Murphy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9034699/kibonge-murphy)

```javascript
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: For typescript support ``const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement);``

Comment: @KibongeMurphy I get the following warning when adding what you recommended. `This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression.sonarlint(typescript:S4325)`

Any ideas why?

Comment: The versions you're running would be helpful to understand what's happening... For now, it looks like you don't need the explicit casting. Try removing the ``as HTMLElement``

Comment: For reference check this: https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot

Comment: now i get `react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: You are importing createRoot from "react-dom" which is not supported. You should instead import it from "react-dom/client"`

Comment: I get this warning from `npx create-react-app` and updating react and react-dom, running ǹpm audit fix [--force]` doesn't even fix the vulnerabilities. Who ships a broken version of React? What a fiasco.

Answer (score 63):

React 18 shipped March 29th, 2022. `ReactDOM.render` has been deprecated in React 18 and currently issues a warning and runs in a compatible mode.

[Deprecations](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#deprecations)

**Deprecations**

- ***`react-dom`: `ReactDOM.render` has been deprecated. Using it will warn and run your app in React 17 mode.***
- `react-dom`: `ReactDOM.hydrate` has been deprecated. Using it will warn and run your app in React 17 mode.
- `react-dom`: `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode` has been deprecated.
- `react-dom`: `ReactDOM.renderSubtreeIntoContainer` has been deprecated.
- `react-dom/server`: `ReactDOMServer.renderToNodeStream` has been deprecated.

To resolve it, you can either revert to a previous version of React or update your index.js file to align with the React 18 syntax.

Example:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: This is a good answer. But if, like me, you're using Typescript, you will need to add something like
```
if (!rootElement)
   throw new Error('Failed to find the root element')
```
before calling createRoot.

Comment: For typescript users, the only thing you need to do is add "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0"
  }. That's it. The code above with createRoot is fine.

Comment: @matdev Yes, move whatever `Link` components you are rendering inside any router component you are rendering. This has nothing to do with React 18. See [error useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70220520/8690857). If you need more help from here it preferable to create a *new* SO post with the specific details and [mcve]. Feel free to ping me here with a link to the post if you like, and I can take a look when available.

Comment: Or just
`const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));`
for those of us who prefer fewer lines. (To replace lines 6 & 7.)

Answer (score 39):

Instead of:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
ReactDom.render(<h1>Your App</h1>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Use:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<h1>Your App</h1>)
```

More details [here](https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/07/15/react-18-adds-new-root-api.html)

Answer (score 16):

Before

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
const container = document.getElementById('app');
render(<App tab="home" />, container);
```

After

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
const container = document.getElementById('app');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App tab="home" />);
```

Before in your *index.js* file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


reportWebVitals();
```

Change it like below into your *index.js* file:

```
import React from 'react';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<React.StrictMode>
  <App />
</React.StrictMode>);


reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: It is not easy to see the diff. And an explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71762741/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 10):

The legacy root API with `ReactDOM.render` has been deprecated in React 18 and replaced with a new root API using `createRoot`. The root of your app is the top-level DOM element that contains all of your rendered components, and is usually a `<div>` with an ID of `root`.

React 18 still has support for `ReactDOM.render` so you technically aren't required to update, but you can't be sure how long this support will last.

You can find a lot more information on the difference between `ReactDOM.render` and `createRoot` at https://thelonecoder.dev/javascript/react-js/reactdom-render-vs-createroot/.

To update to the new root API, change your `index.js` file to something like the following:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

Comment: The warning says your application is going to be behaving as React 17, is this not actually required to trigger the React 18 ?

Answer (score 7):

To provide more or less an equivalent to prior versions of React, I use this slightly condensed version of the above, still surrounding the `<App>` with the `<React.StrictMode>`.

Another reason I condense this is that - in my specific pipeline - I never need to access the root variable, consequently, chaining statements together makes more sense to me, and the whole file is just five lines of code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

import './index.css';
import App from './App';

    ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(<React.StrictMode><App /></React.StrictMode>);
```

(P.S.: Don't forget if you need the webvitals functionality to also add to the above code)

Finally, I save this starter code as a Live Template using the WebStorm IDE. Depending on your IDE your snippets may be called differently, but the idea should be similar.

Comment: your "runnable" code cannot run in Stackoverflow with `import` statements

Answer (score 7):

As you said, you created your React app using: *npx create-react-app my-app*.

Your index.js must look like this after the command executes:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Your code after edits mentioned in the console:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: your "runnable" code cannot run in stackoverflow with `import` statements

Comment: While you are right that "Your index.js must look like this after the command executes." the question remains: Why does create-react-app bootstrap an application with an error in it? It's a brand new app running the latest version. Is there a reason behind the developers shipping it in a broken state?

Answer (score 6):

As your error states, ReactDOM.render is no longer supported. So use the new createRoot.

As you can see from the code below, (which was pulled from [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html)) all you have to do is replace ReactDOM.render with createRoot.

```
// Before
import { render } from 'react-dom';
const container = document.getElementById('app');
render(<App tab="home" />, container);

// After
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
const container = document.getElementById('app');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App tab="home" />);
```

Answer (score 5):

In your *index.js* file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
```

Use this before React version 18

```
// ReactDOM.render(
//   <React.StrictMode>
//     <App />
//   </React.StrictMode>,
//   document.getElementById("root")
// );
```

Use this in React version 18

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

Comment: Why is the second part (seemingly) outcommented?

Comment: With this solution I get the error:  index.tsx:19 Uncaught Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component. Any workaround please ?

Answer (score 4):

If your application is using React-Router, then the following code will work fine:

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

It will work perfectly (with react-router).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Since I'm new to React, I'm not sure if this is a relevant question, but it looks like the element Id won't always be 'root'. In that case, it seems the createRoot() call would probably be something else. Is there a more general answer?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createRoot}  from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
root.render
  (
    <App />
  )
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71698440/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

It can be solved by upgrading to v14.

In an older version we experienced an issue.

Just install the latest version:

```
npm i @testing-library/react@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

In React 18. For those that are using custom [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) configurations, follow *[React Refresh Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin)*. They have some [HMR](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/) built in.

We are supposed to use *fast refresh* that has been developed by the React team.

It resolved that error message for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {createRoot} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "./styles.css";


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app"));
root.render( <App />);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

const App: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchOpenWeatherData("Toronto")
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <img src="icon.png" />
    </div>
  );
};

const rootEl = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(rootEl);
const root = createRoot(rootEl);
root.render(<App />);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Do it actually run? Stack Snippets are ***not*** for general formatting.

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*

Comment: Perhaps somebody else can chime in?