# React Testing Library gives console error for ReactDOM.render in React 18

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-dom

After updating to React 18 or creating a new React 18 app from `create-react-app`, when I run the `yarn test` command, it gives a `console.error` as a Warning for each of the `render` methods used in any of the tests as:

> console.error
> Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more: https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot

As seen in the screenshot:
[image: react testing library warning]

As React Testing Library doesn't seem to support React 18 methodology as of now.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668256/deprecation-notice-reactdom-render-is-no-longer-supported-in-react-18

Answer (score 81, accepted):

To solve the react testing library error:

`"ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18, update the version of the react testing library."`

Open your terminal in the root directory of your project and run the following commands:

```
npm install --save-dev @testing-library/react@latest
npm install --save-dev @testing-library/jest-dom@latest
npm install --save-dev @testing-library/user-event@latest
```

Make sure to update the versions of all react testing library packages you are using.

Your index.js file should use the new createRoot API to render your application.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Now you should be able to start your tests without getting the error.

App.test.js

```
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders react component', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const divElement = screen.getByText(/hello world/i);
  expect(divElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: to be honest, at first, I didn't believe your answer. because I just create new app using create-react-app so I guessed that the react and react-testing library should be latest version. but in fact react version was 18 but testing library version was old, so I tried your answer and the issue disappeared.

Comment: This is nice for the `App` file itself, but what about other testing components in the project? Should we render them every time we are creating their tests?

Comment: Thank you! Along with above listed packages, I need to upgrade @types/jest to latest due to dependency conflicts. `npm install --save-dev @types/jest@latest`

Answer (score 12):

uninstall `@testing-library/react-hook` and import `renderHook` from `@testing-library/react`

```
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react";
```

see here https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library/issues/826#issuecomment-1100650242

Comment: @testing-library/react does not support waitForNextUpdate and async operations the same way @testing-library/react-hook does

Answer (score 0):

For quick update of all the libraries you can use next commands:

1. for update to new major version:
   `npm install -g npm-check-updates`
2. upgrade versions in package.json:
   `ncu -u`
3. or npm install, in case your project hasn't node_modules:
   `npm update`

Comment: I would be careful with `ncu`. It's a great _tool_ but it will also update dependencies  that are version locked (i.e. to a specific version or to a specific major version). Ultimately, just have to be paying attention.