# styles are not applied (webpack)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I just started to learn webpack and how to use it
I have a problem, that content from 'App.js' displayed on the screen, but styles from 'App.scss' not applied and dont paint  tag

However, I have this issue in console:
**Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agG61.png)

```js
//App.js

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Webpack is work</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
//App.scss

h1 {
    color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
//index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test Tusk</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="index.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***index.js:***

```
require('file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!./index.html');
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import  App  from './App';
import './App.scss';


ReactDOM.render(
<React.StrictMode>
    <App/>
</React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById('app'));
```

Config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'index.bundle.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3010,
        static: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader', 
                    'css-loader', 
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

Package Json:

```
{
  "name": "testtusk",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.robinwieruch.de/webpack-sass/ perhaps this can help you, since you made no statements about your webpack config.

Comment: i made webpack statemants in config exactly like this web-site shows

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668256/deprecation-notice-reactdom-render-is-no-longer-supported-in-react-18 for your react error (which should still be independent of your scss error)

Comment: yeah, react error solved. but scss not work still, as u sad

Comment: can you add your webpack config and your installed dependencies? i think your code for importing etc. is fine.

Comment: I added config & package.json

Comment: locally it's working for me. pls try for `static` in your config: `path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist)`