# React | not showing contents on the site

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json, node-modules

I'm creating a react app. The elements I add to my **App.js** file are not appearing on the site when I run `npm start`, the **index.html** elements will load, however, the rest will not.

Here is my code:
(Note: I'm using an earlier version of `react-router-dom` which is why I'm using `Switch` instead of `Routes`)

**App.js**

```js
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact />
      </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

**index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.js';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

**Navbar.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Navbar() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
  const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);
  return (
      <>
          <nav className="navBar">
              <div className='navbar-container'>
                  <Link to="/" className="navbar-logo">
                  <img alt="collabrity" src="images/icon.png" width="25" height="25"></img>collabrity
                  </Link>
                  <div className='menu-icon' onClick={handleClick}>
                      <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
          </div>
          <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
            <li className='nav-item'>
              <Link to='/' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
              </div>
        </nav>
      </>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

---

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "NAME",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

All I've tried to do so far is create a navigation bar menu, but nothing will appear on the site (even if just putting something like `<h1>Test</h1>` within the app function).

Thank you in advance for any push in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, I think you have to specify the component that should render on this route `<Route path="/" exact />`,  you can use `component`  prop. ` <Route path="/" exact  component="COMPONENT_NAME"/>` https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-rain-jewizq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but ReactDOM.render is deprecated in react version 18. Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668256/deprecation-notice-reactdom-render-is-no-longer-supported-in-react-18

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually rendering anything for the route. For the Route component you either have to pass in a component to the component prop or add it as a child.

```js
<Route path="/" exact component={SomeComponent} />
{/* OR */}
<Route path="/" exact>
  <SomeComponent />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Nawak Khalifah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11942123/nawaf-khalifah) pointed me in the right direction by linking me to their code sandbox.

I altered my **index.js** file to look more like:

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

While also passing a component for the route. This seemed to fix it.

Thanks so much.