# what does reactDOM.createroot does in React?

Tags: reactjs

When creating `react` applications, what does **`reactDOM.createroot`** do? Does it create virtual DOM?

Comment: your question is already answered in React documentation here is the  link - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-client.html#:~:text=Reference-,createRoot(),createRoot(container)%3B%20root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

createRoot() method is going to replace ReactDOM.render() in React 18.

I suggest looking at the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-client.html#createroot

And here's the link to another question about the deprecation of the render method: [Deprecation notice: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668256/deprecation-notice-reactdom-render-is-no-longer-supported-in-react-18)

Answer (score 1):

`reactDOM.createroot` use to create new container in virtual dom
like you want to inject some component dynamically you can use is like this

```
   //here is container where you will add dynamic dom
  const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(document.getElementById('bodyArea'));
    

//here is dynamic dom
     root.render(
                  <MyPopupModal>
                   <TestComonent></TestComponent>
                  </Modal>
                );
```