# RTKQery React 18 warning => Warning: Use createRoot instead

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rtk-query

I'm testing [this example](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/tree/master/examples/query/react/authentication-with-extrareducers) of RTKQuery and when I'm running it, it will throw this error

```
Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running
```

I checked
[Deprecation notice: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668256/deprecation-notice-reactdom-render-is-no-longer-supported-in-react-18) and I couldn't find the right answer for it.

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react'

import App from './App'
import { store } from './app/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ChakraProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </ChakraProvider>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

Comment: After changing `ReactDOM.render` to `ReactDOM.createRoot` the warning still exist?

Comment: yes, it still exists