# How to use react v18 with nextjs v12.3.1 - Suspense boundary and StartTransition and new createRoot

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-suspense, hydration

I am trying to figure out how to get a react app to work next js.

I am using this [boilerplate app template](https://github.com/NoQuarterTeam/boilerplate), but with react v18 (and next v 12.3.1).

I tried changing _app.tsx so that it is now wrapped in a suspense boundary:

```
 <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <ApolloProvider 
          client={apolloClient}
        >
            {getLayout(
              <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}> <Component {...pageProps} />
              </React.Suspense>
              )
            }
        </ApolloProvider>
      </ChakraProvider>
    </>
  )
```

but when I try to start the local host, I get a message that says:

> Error: This Suspense boundary received an update before it finished
> hydrating. This caused the boundary to switch to client rendering. The
> usual way to fix this is to wrap the original update in
> startTransition.

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668256/deprecation-notice-reactdom-render-is-no-longer-supported-in-react-18) and am trying to follow the principles it describes but I cannot find corresponding concepts in next.js, index.tsx. That file has:

```
import * as React from "react"
import { ColorModeScript } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import Document, { Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from "next/document"

export default class AppDocument extends Document {
  static getInitialProps(ctx: any) {
    return Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <meta name="theme-color" key="theme-color" content="#000000" />
          <meta name="description" content="description goes here" key="description" />
          <meta property="og:title" content="title goes here" key="title" />
          <meta property="og:description" content="add a description" key="og:description" />
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossOrigin="true" />
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <ColorModeScript initialColorMode="light" />
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

The other post suggests finding where the index.js file has:

```
ReactDom.render(<h1>Your App</h1>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

and replacing it with

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<h1>Your App</h1>)
```

What is the equivalent of that ReactDOM.render in nextjs? Does anyone know how to get a page to load using react v18 and next 12.3.1?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. if you want a page to render in Next place in the pages directory i.e `pages/about.js`
Link to docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages)
The boilerplate i.e`/packages/web/src` should work fine.

```
  <Suspense fallback={<div>loading<div/>}>
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
        {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
     </ApolloProvider>
  </ChakraProvider>
</Suspense>
```

For your lazy import use [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import)

```
const DynamicHeader = dynamic(() => import('../components/header'), {
    suspense: true,
     })
```