# <Link> tag from React Router Dom V6 not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create a header with links to their respective componenets. Using the **a** tag to redirect to a component works fine.

The Routes also work properly when the URL is changed manually by me. But when I use the **Link** tag to redirect it breaks the site and renders a blank page.
Take a look at my code below...

**App.js**

```
<Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Hero />}></Route>
        <Route path="experience" element={<Experience />}></Route>
        <Route path="photos" element={<Photography />}></Route>
      </Routes>
</Router>
```

**Header.js**

```
 <nav>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <Link to="/">Home</Link> // using Link renders blank page
      </li>
      <li>
         <Link to="/experience">Experience</Link> // using Link renders blank page
     </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/photos">Photography</a> // works fine
      </li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

I don't even need to click the Link for the site to break, it automatically renders a blank page when the **Link** tag is used.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong

Comment: Try `<Route path="/experience" element={<Experience />}></Route>` Maybe you forgot the slash.

Comment: the routing works well but the Links aren't. Adding the"/" before the path also makes no difference

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: "it automatically renders a blank page" - this is usually because of a major Javascript error in the application (particularly one encountered while React is rendering). Did you check the browser console?

Comment: stupid question perhaps, but I feel I need to ask: you did import the Link component in the module where you're using it, right?

Comment: please add full components

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you! I found what was causing the issue and fixed it.

Comment: And thanks to everyone for your insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically the issue was that I'd used the Link tag outside the React Router Context. That was breaking the website.

**App.js (Before)**

```
function App() {
 return (
 <Layout>
  <div className="App">
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Hero />}></Route>
        <Route path="experience" element={<Experience />}></Route>
        <Route path="photos" element={<Photography />}></Route>
        <Route
          path="*"
          element={
            <main style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>
              <p>There's nothing here!</p>
            </main>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  </div>
</Layout>
);
}
```

**App.js (After)**

```
function App() {
 return (
 <div className="App">
  <Router>
    <Layout>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Hero />}></Route>
        <Route path="experience" element={<Experience />}></Route>
        <Route path="photos" element={<Photography />}></Route>
        <Route
          path="*"
          element={
            <main style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>
              <p>There's nothing here!</p>
            </main>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </Layout>
  </Router>
</div>
);
}
```

You can find some more deatils realted to this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70220413/error-usehref-may-be-used-only-in-the-context-of-a-router-component-it-wor)

Answer (score 0):

The Header component is outside of the Router context, That seems to be the problem.