# react router dom not working when changing the path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

I am trying to use the router in react but I get nothing when changing the path, you can check the code here [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-matsumoto-p49zlp?file=/src/Layout.js) ..............................

```js
import React from "react";
import Layout from "./Layout";
import Home from "./Home";
import About from "./About";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      </Router>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

Comment: capitalization matters. path="/About" and to="/about" have different capitalization so the router does not find the it. Use either 'about' or 'About'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `<div>{children}</div>` inside `<Router>`, then in `app.js` remove `Router`. Because that has already been declared in `<Layout>`

**Layout.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>

        <div>{children}</div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "./Layout";
import Home from "./Home";
import About from "./About";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Layout>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Your current code will output the following:**

```
<div>
  <Router>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    <Link to="/about">About</Link>
  </Router>

  {/* Children (App.js) */}
   <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
 {/* Children (App.js) */}
</div>
```

You don't need two instances of `<Router>`.

This how it should be:

```
  <Router>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    
    {/* Children (App.js) */}
     <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
    </Routes>
    {/* Children (App.js) */}
  </Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove Router from your route wrap

import React from "react"; import Layout from "./Layout"; import Home from "./Home"; import About from "./About"; import { BrowserRouter as Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() { return (

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
</Routes>
```

); }

export default App;

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, that you have two different Routers in your Application.

You need to move the Layout Component inside your Routercomponent in App.js
[image]

And then delete the second router inside of Layout.

[image]

More info here:
[Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component. It works when I directly put the url as localhost:3000/experiences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70220413/error-usehref-may-be-used-only-in-the-context-of-a-router-component-it-wor)