# Router 6.4: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

**This is not duplicate of** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70220413/error-usehref-may-be-used-only-in-the-context-of-a-router-component-it-wor) because the answers there don't address how to do this with **router 6.4** (namely with `createBrowserRouter` and `createRoutesFromElements`).
Also not sure if component layout is similar.

---

This is my code:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Route path="/" element={<Test />} />
      <Route path="dashboard" element={<Test2 />} />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
);

const { Header, Content, Sider } = Layout;
function App() {
  return (
    <Layout style={{ height: "100%" }}>
      <Header className="header">
        <Menu theme="dark" mode="horizontal" defaultSelectedKeys={["2"]} items={items1} />
      </Header>
      <Layout>
        <Content
          style={{
            padding: 24,
            margin: 0,
            minHeight: 280,
          }}
        >
          <RouterProvider router={router} />
        </Content>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

I am getting error

> useHref() may be used only in the context of a  component

I understand this is related to my `Links` not embedded within `Router`, but using this **new API of 6.4 react router** how do I solve this problem?

Comment: I specifically  mentioned that my question wasn't duplicate and explained the reasons and it still got closed?

Comment: It's the same issue. The `Link` component still needs to be rendered within a routing context provided by a router. RRDv6.4 didn't change how the routing context works.

Comment: @DrewReese I don't know how to create that routing context because I am **using the new API** that's the problem. So how do I create that routing context in my example?

Comment: You created it with `<RouterProvider router={router} />`. You are passing the router there. The links need to be used inside the router.

Comment: @DrewReese Well but you can see I have rendered that inside the `Content` component because the routes must be drawn there, and the links in the Header. Do you see the problem? What can I do in such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with the new RRDv6.4 Data APIs and Data Routers, the `Link` components still need to be rendered within the routing context. You can move all the `App` component layout to be a layout route configured when you create the router.

Example:

```
const { Header, Content, Sider } = Layout;

const AppLayout = () => (
  <Layout style={{ height: "100%" }}>
    <Header className="header">
      <Menu
        theme="dark"
        mode="horizontal"
        defaultSelectedKeys={["2"]}
        items={items1}
      />
    </Header>
    <Layout>
      <Content
        style={{
          padding: 24,
          margin: 0,
          minHeight: 280,
        }}
      >
        <Outlet />
      </Content>
    </Layout>
  </Layout>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<Test />} />
      <Route path="dashboard" element={<Test2 />} />
    </Route>
  )
);
```

...

```
function App() {
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will look into this, I suggest you also update this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70220520/20356518

Comment: @john I could do that, it's the same underlying issue, but it's caused by different scenarios.

Comment: One more thing, is this correct: 
`<Route path="/" element={<App />}> <Route path="/" element={<Test2 />} />
      </Route>` I want slightly different layout. When user goes to '/', by default I want to show `Test2` inside App. Sorry for format will try to fix it

Comment: @john I just used the two routes from your example, but no, you can't have two routes rendering on the same path. Oh, wait, the `App` is a parent route. Yeah, you can do the routes like that.

Comment: Yeah it is parent but what is confusing me is that I used **same path** on parent and child is this accepted in such situations?

Comment: @john Yeah, it's fine. You may also see *that* child route path that matches the parent route referred to as the index route, so you'd see something like `<Route path="/" element={....}><Route index element={.....} /> .... </Route>`.

Comment: If I set paths on children are they relative to parent if child has route "a" and parent has route "b", to access child should I visit: "b/a"? This is last question - thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249131/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-john).