# React Router V6 - useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router, react-router-dom, enzyme

I have installed react-router-domV6. I am having the above error when I run my very basic test using Jest-Enzyme:

```
expect(shallow(<CustomerListTable customers={mockCustomers} />).length).toEqual(1);
```

I already came across this [similar issue mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425884/react-router-v6-error-useroutes-may-be-used-only-in-the-context-of-a-route), but I am already doing the provided answers. Even tried doing the `import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";`. What am I missing here?

**index.js**

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
...

ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
          ...
            <BrowserRouter>
              <AuthProvider>
                <App />
              </AuthProvider>
            </BrowserRouter>
          ...
  </StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useRoutes } from "react-router-dom";
import Routing from "./routes";
import useAuth from "./hooks/useAuth";
import { CreateCustomTheme } from "./theme";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import useSettings from "./hooks/useSettings";
import useScrollReset from "./hooks/useScrollReset";
import SplashScreen from "./components/splashScreen/SplashScreen";

const App = () => {
  const content = useRoutes(Routing());
  const { settings } = useSettings();
  const auth = useAuth();

  useScrollReset();

  const theme = CreateCustomTheme({
    direction: settings.direction,
    responsiveFontSizes: settings.responsiveFontSizes,
    roundedCorners: settings.roundedCorners,
    theme: settings.theme,
  });
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      {auth.isInitialized ? content : <SplashScreen />}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems the `CustomerListTable` component you are testing *in isolation* doesn't have access to a routing context it's expecting as when it's rendered in the app normally. It's completely normal to need to wrap components when testing them with providers (redux, themes/styling, localization, ***routing***, etc...) that are providing specific React Context values the component is accessing, typically via React hooks.

For the unit test you should wrap the component with the providers it's expecting to have.

```
expect(shallow(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <CustomerListTable customers={mockCustomers} />
  </BrowserRouter>
).length).toEqual(1);
```

It's been a long time since I've used Enzyme, so I'm not certain the `shallow` render will still work, but if it doesn't then swap to the full `mount` test renderer.

Answer (score 25):

**To fix this issue, you can direct mock your useNavigate() like this after all the imports for the file in which you are writing the test case:-**

```
const mockUsedNavigate = jest.fn();
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
   ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useNavigate: () => mockUsedNavigate,
}));
```

Comment: saved my day ... :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `"react-router-dom": "^6.12.0",`

For unit testing I solved the issue like this:

1. import memory router:

```js
import { MemoryRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
```

2. Wrap the component with the router

```
<Router>
    <CustomerListTable customers={mockCustomers} />
</Router>
```